# Summing up values with criteria and sumif doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Accounting Record A     Accounting Record B

```
Date             Amount         Date            Amount
12/17/2016   1,800.00   10/13/2016  -1,800.00
12/21/2016   5,200.00   12/10/2016  -5,200.00
12/25/2016   25,000.00  12/12/2016  -25,000.00
12/30/2016   37,000.00  11/2/2016   -37,000.00
```

These are two accounting records which I am going to add up. What I want is to have the sum of the amounts for December 2016, so the estimated output is 38800 (1800+37000 since 5200 and 25000 are canceled out). I used this formula `=SUMIF(A3:A6,AND(MONTH(A3:A6)=12,YEAR(A3:A6)=2016),B3:B6)+SUMIF(C3:C6,AND(MONTH(C3:C6)=12,YEAR(C3:C6)=2016),D3:D6)`

but it returned 0. May I know the correct formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AND` and `OR` operators are not array friendly. Your best friend here is `SUMPRODUCT` with aligned arrays, in a way that permits the multiplication of summed values by the appropriate logical conditions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B6*(MONTH(A3:A6)=12)*(YEAR(A3:A6)=2016))
  + SUMPRODUCT(D3:D6*(MONTH(C3:C6)=12)*(YEAR(C3:C6)=2016))
```